# Water fried iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, damage

I dropped my phone into a pool a while ago, and didn't realize until about 30 minutes after. When I try to hook it up to the computer, it doesn't recognize the device, the iPhone wont turn on, it is ruined. But I was wondering if there's a way to get files off of it even with the computer not recognizing the device. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would be nice if you had iCloud backups turned on..

Comment: have you backed up your iPhone through iTunes or iCloud ?

Comment: Yes i had it on but i dont have another apple product to get them off of

Answer (score -1):

You have no way to restore data, all gone